# kivyMD APK crashes on start up (android)

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

> I help me figure out what the problem may be.
>
> Hi, I am having issues running my Kivy MD app on an android device.
> After compiling my app into an apk I use a USB stick to transfer the
> file onto an android phone. The app is successfully installed and
> loads up the kivy splash screen but then the app closes. Please note
> that  I am not able to obtain a logcast as my mobile cannot connect
> using 'run'(i have tried many methods but this isn't the issue)

- resources:
- kivy
- kivymd
- buildozer
- python
- -Ubuntu 20.04

I simplified things by writing a simple code to run in order to see if the issue was with my initial complex code: below is the code i ran:

```
1.main.py(including my kv)
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList

kv = """
ScreenManager:
    StartUpScreen:
    ContactScreen:
    OptionsScreen:

<StartUpScreen>:
    name: 'startup'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'ViV'
        halign: 'center'
        font_style: "H2"
        theme_text_color: 'Primary'

    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: 'NEXT'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'options'
        elevation: 10

<ContactScreen>:
    name: 'contact us'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDLabel:
            text:'CONTACT INFORMATION'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'top'
            halign: 'center'
            font_style: "H5"
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            row_default_height: 150
            row_force_default: True
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            padding: dp(10), dp(10)
            spacing: dp(15)
            #images here
            SmartTileWithLabel:
                source: "banner.jpg"
                nocache: True
                mipmap: True
                elevation: 10


        MDList:
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:  'contact.viv.rsa@gmail.com'
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon:"email"



        MDList:
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:  'Call us on  081 424 9121\\n\ 083 730 3544'
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon:"phone"

        MDList:
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Check us out : @viv_rsa'
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon:"instagram"
                    

        MDList:
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Find us on Facebook: VIV App'
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon:"facebook"

        Widget:
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: 'BACK'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.05}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'options'
        elevation: 10

<OptionsScreen>:
    name: "options"
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: "COVERGIRL.jpg"
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "PRODUCTS & SERVICES"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.55}
        #on_release:root.manager.current= "city"
        elevation: 10


    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "CONTACT US"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.45}
        on_release: root.manager.current= "contact us"
        elevation: 10

    MDLabel:
        text: 'not designed for children'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.08}
        font_style: "Overline"
        color: 255,255,255,1
"""


class StartUpScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ContactScreen(Screen):
    pass


class OptionsScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(StartUpScreen(name='startup'))
sm.add_widget(ContactScreen(name='contact us'))
sm.add_widget(OptionsScreen(name='options'))


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return screen




MainApp().run()
```

`2.buildozer.spec file`

```
> [app]
> 
> # (str) Title of your application title = VIV
> 
> # (str) Package name package.name = MainApp
> 
> # (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging) package.domain = org.viv
> 
> # (str) Source code where the main.py live source.dir = .
> 
> # (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files) source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,xml,iml
> 
> # (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
> #source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png
> 
> # (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
> #source.exclude_exts = spec
> 
> # (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
> #source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin
> 
> # (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
> #source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg
> 
> # (str) Application versioning (method 1) version = 0.2
> 
> # (str) Application versioning (method 2)
> # version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
> # version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py
> 
> # (list) Application requirements
> # comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy requirements = python3,kivy,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,pygments,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15
> 
> # (str) Custom source folders for requirements
> # Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes requirements.source.kivymd =kivymd
> 
> # (list) Garden requirements
> #garden_requirements =
> 
> # (str) Presplash of the application
> #presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png
> 
> # (str) Icon of the application
> #icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png
> 
> # (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all) orientation = portrait
> 
> # (list) List of service to declare
> #services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY
> 
> #
> # OSX Specific
> #
> 
> #
> # author = © Copyright Info
> 
> # change the major version of python used by the app
> #osx.python_version = 3
> 
> # Kivy version to use
> #osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1
> 
> #
> # Android specific
> #
> 
> # (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not fullscreen = 1
> 
> # (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
> # Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
> # red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
> # darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
> # olive, purple, silver, teal. android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF
> 
> # (list) Permissions android.permissions = INTERNET
> 
> # (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible. android.api = 29
> 
> # (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
> #android.minapi = 21
> 
> # (int) Android SDK version to use
> #android.sdk = 20
> 
> # (str) Android NDK version to use
> #android.ndk = 19b
> 
> # (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
> #android.ndk_api = 21
> 
> # (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
> #android.private_storage = True
> 
> # (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
> #android.ndk_path =
> 
> # (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
> #android.sdk_path =
> 
> # (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
> #android.ant_path =
> 
> # (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
> # This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
> # when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
> # android.skip_update = False
> 
> # (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
> # agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
> # the default, you will be shown the license when first running
> # buildozer.
> # android.accept_sdk_license = False
> 
> # (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
> #android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity
> 
> # (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
> # android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
> 
> # (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
> #android.whitelist =
> 
> # (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
> #android.whitelist_src =
> 
> # (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
> #android.blacklist_src =
> 
> # (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
> # their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
> # down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
> # OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
> #android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar
> 
> # (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
> # directory containing the files)
> #android.add_src =
> 
> # (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
> # bootstrap)
> #android.add_aars =
> 
> # (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
> # bootstrap)
> #android.gradle_dependencies =
> 




> 
> # (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
> #android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
> #android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
> #android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
> #android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
> #android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so
> 
> # (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
> # Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
> #android.wakelock = False
> 
> # (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
> #android.meta_data =
> 
> # (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
> # project.properties automatically.)
> #android.library_references =
> 
> # (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
> #android.uses_library =
> 
> # (str) Android logcat filters to use
> #android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D
> 
> # (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
> #android.copy_libs = 1
> 
> # (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64 android.arch = armeabi-v7a
> 
> # (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
> # this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
> # android.numeric_version = 1
> 
> #
> # Python for android (p4a) specific
> #
> 
> # (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
> #p4a.fork = kivy
> 
> # (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
> #p4a.branch = master
> 
> # (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
> #p4a.source_dir =
> 
> # (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
> #p4a.local_recipes =
> 
> # (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
> #p4a.hook =
> 
> # (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
> # p4a.bootstrap = sdl2
> 
> # (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
> #p4a.port =
> 
> 
> #
> # iOS specific
> #
> 
> # (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
> #ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
> # Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout: ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
> ios.kivy_ios_branch = master
> 
> # Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
> # Uncomment to use a custom checkout
> #ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
> # Or specify URL and branch ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0
> 
> # (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
> # Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
> #ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"
> 
> # (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
> #ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s
> 
> 
> [buildozer]
> 
> # (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output)) log_level = 2
> 
> # (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True) warn_on_root = 1
> 
> # (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
> # build_dir = ./.buildozer
> 
> # (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
> # bin_dir = ./bin
> 
> #    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> #    List as sections
> #
> #    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
> #    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
> #    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
> #    Instead of doing:
> #
> #[app]
> #source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
> #
> #    This can be translated into:
> #
> #[app:source.exclude_patterns]
> #license
> #data/audio/*.wav
> #data/images/original/*
> #
> 
> 
> #    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> #    Profiles
> #
> #    You can extend section / key with a profile
> #    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
> #    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
> #    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
> #
> #[app@demo]
> #title = My Application (demo)
> #
> #[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
> #images/hd/*
> #
> #    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
> #
> #buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

3. This is the log i get when i successfully ran my app in comand prompt(windows)

[This is the log i get when i successfully ran my app in comand prompt(windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDGdD.png)

Comment: Go to developer options on your android and enable usb-debugging then try running logcat. Logcat is the only way out here

Comment: @ankit thanks but I did advise that that wasn’t my issue. I tried all that and I am past trying to resolve that. 
I need to know if I set up my Buildozer file correctly

Comment: Why have you commented everything in buildozer file?

Comment: No I haven’t. It’s the format of the file. The text exceed to a new line so it looks like it’s I commented. If you familiar with the buildozer.spec you will know what’s in commented and wat is

Comment: Oh ok. In requirements for kivymd instead of `https://www.github.com...` it will be `git+https://github.com....`

Comment: @Ankit Thank you but what’s the difference?

Comment: until you write `git+` it won't understand what it has to do with the link. `git+link` tells it to use git to clone the link. Try changing it and then run your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So that didn’t work for me what worked was adding kivy==2.0.0, kivymd==0.104.1

Answer (score 1):

In your requirements line in your buildozer.spec file, use this

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMd/archive/master.zip,pygments,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow,docutils,plyer
```

This worked for me.